# InfoPath Form - Multiple Content Types

Tags: list, infopath, content-type

I have a SharePoint List where I need one set of users to use one form and another set to use another.

I've enabled multiple content types and built out my two separate forms, how do I publish and how do users differentiate between what form they see?

Answer (score 0):

> I've enabled multiple content types and built out my two separate forms, how do I publish

With SharePoint Designer you can specify forms for every content type. Navigate to your list (in SPD) and click the InfoPath button in the ribbon.

> and how do users differentiate between what form they see?

They differentiate by selecting the different content types. In the list, they can select the content type in the drop-down list under *Items* -> *New Item*. [You could also create a direct links to *new form* of the content type.](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/a/97538/43765)

Comment: Thank You - One of my forms is for managers to edit existing items, created using my first form. Is there a way of enabling selection when editing the item in InfoPath?

Comment: So while editing an item you want to launch a different form? Or what do you mean with "enabling selection when editing"?

Comment: Sorry to be clear - One group of users will create a list entry using form A. I need another group of users to edit that list item using form B. Is there a way users can select what form to use when editing an existing item. Having multiple pages on the same form isn't an option for me unfortunately.

Comment: Hm.. You want to have different edit forms for one content type? I don't think that this is possible. Creating different sections in your InfoPath form and hiding/showing them conditionally is no option?